# I accidentally deleted all the references from my Xamarin.Forms app. How do I get them back?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I ran a "project normalizer" tool to clean up the csproj file but it doesn't seem to like .NET Standard projects and it deleted all my references! Which ones do I need to add back for Xamarin to work again, and where can I find them?

Comment: I assume your project is based on PackageReference and not on packages.config.
In this case, in your .csproj files, you should have all <PackageReference ...> required for your application. If you rebuild project or solution or if you run Restore Nuget Packages on your solution, it should get all the references automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I created a second Xamarin.Forms app and read what references I need from there: Xamarin.Essentials and Xamarin.Forms, both from nuget.